# how to push a selected value into top of the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown with vertical scroll bar. What i need is if i select any text from a drop down, it should be on the top of the scroll top. Ex. I have 10 items in dropdown. If i select 3rd item, the selected item should be visible on the top of scroll bar. 
I have try with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").on("click", function(){
       var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
       alert(scroll);
    });
});
```

Just I have try this, don't know how to do this. Help me

Comment: Would you provide example or HTML for more help?

Comment: Could you provide html code too.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information.

Answer (score 0):

> With prependTo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").on("click", function(){
        $(this).prependTo(".nano")
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nano has-scrollbar">
        <p>jerrin</p>
        <p>stephen</p>
        <p>augustin</p>
        <p>yeswanth</p>
        <p>irfan</p>
        <p>aashik</p>
        <p>dinesh</p>
        <p>zaid</p>
        <p>mari</p>
        <p>aravinth</p>
        <p>asf</p>
        <p>qwe</p>
        <p>ewq</p>
        <p>fhg</p>
        <p>uyt</p>
        <p>rty</p>
        <p>rty</p>
        <p>rty</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

> With scroll

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("p").on("click", function(){
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        },100);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nano has-scrollbar">
        <p>jerrin</p>
        <p>stephen</p>
        <p>augustin</p>
        <p>yeswanth</p>
        <p>irfan</p>
        <p>aashik</p>
        <p>dinesh</p>
        <p>zaid</p>
        <p>mari</p>
        <p>aravinth</p>
        <p>asf</p>
        <p>qwe</p>
        <p>ewq</p>
        <p>fhg</p>
        <p>uyt</p>
        <p>rty</p>
        <p>rty</p>
        <p>rty</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```